# Pillow convert png to 8bit bitmap

Tags: python-3.x, bitmap, png, python-imaging-library, 8-bit

i tried to convert 8bit PNGs to 8bit(256indexed palette) Bitmap image,
but Pillow is keep vomiting crappy outcome.

this is what i tried.

```
image = Image.open(file)
image = image.convert('P')
pp = image.getpalette()
pp[0] = 255
pp[1] = 0
pp[2] = 255
image.putpalette(pp)
```

or

```
image = Image.open(file)
image = image.convert('P')
image.save(blabla.bmp)
```

and this is the outcome what i expected to see.
this is an actual bitmap(done by Photoshop.)
[Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVLmd.png)
and this is what Pillow did:
[Pillow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6THU.png)
what kind of joke is this ?!
and it even got cropped out
what should i do to convert it correctly?

Original Image:

[image]

Comment: could you post the original image, so that we can perform tests on it?

Comment: Oh okay thanks :)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0g5q.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open image
image = Image.open('feather.png')

# Quantize to 256 colours using fast octree method
result = image.quantize(colors=256, method=2)
```

[image]

Comment: @MarkSetchell Great Answer (+1) btw can you please explain me how does `Image.quantize()` work differently then converting the image to `P` mode via `convert("P")` . Secondly, what does fast octree method did in this code? I ran your code without the `method = 2` argument in `quantize()` and got the same results.

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Hello Vasu, I'm sorry, I have no contact with the PIL authors nor any insight into why they choose to do anything any particular way. I just have some experience using PIL/Pillow and that's the way I have learned to get the best results.

Comment: i checked your method now and it only works in PNG but same shit happens when i try to save as 'P'type bitmap.

Comment: i think it's because of alpha channels. alpha channels are not being removed smoothly..