# Python PIL remove every alpha channel completely

Tags: python, bitmap, png, python-imaging-library, rgba

I tried so hard to converting PNG to Bitmap smoothly but failed every time.

but now I think I might found a reason.
it's because of the alpha channels.
('feather' in Photoshop)

Input image:

[image]

Output I've expected:

[image]

Current output:

[image]

I want to convert it to 8bit Bitmap and colour every invisible(alpha) pixels to purple(#FF00FF) and set them to dot zero. (very first palette)

but apparently, the background area and the invisible area around the actual image has a different colour.
i want all of them coloured same as background.
what should i do?

i tried these three

```
image = Image.open(file).convert('RGB')


image = Image.open(file)
image = image.convert('P')
pp = image.getpalette()
pp[0] = 255
pp[1] = 0
pp[2] = 255
image.putpalette(pp)


image = Image.open('feather.png')
result = image.quantize(colors=256, method=2)
```

the third method looks better but it becomes the same when I save it as a bitmap.

I just want to get it over now. I wasted too much time on this.

[image: output with background removed]

if i remove background from the output file,
it still looks awkward.

Comment: desired output image, and problemo image are the same (at least at visual level). So what is the problem?

Comment: @VasuDeo.S yes, on visual level it's same but colours around blue are not #FF00FF. they are like #FC01FF #FF08FF and more.. they are just similar color not exactly #FF00FF

Comment: Do you want to save the image as `.bmp` extension?

Comment: @VasuDeo.S yes. that's why colouring background with specific color matters. to separate background area and image area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is kind of misleading as You stated:-

> I want to convert it to 8bit Bitmap and colour every invisible(alpha) pixels to purple(#FF00FF) and set them to dot zero. (very first palette)

But in the description you gave an input image having no alpha channel. Luckily, I have seen your previous question [Convert PNG to 8 bit bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800095/pillow-convert-png-to-8bit-bitmap), therefore I obtained the image containing alpha (that you mentioned in the description) but didn't posted.

**HERE IS THE IMAGE WITH ALPHA:-**

[image]

Now we have to obtain `.bmp` equivalent of this image, in `P` mode.

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(r"Image_loc")

new_img = Image.new("RGB", (image.size[0],image.size[1]), (255, 0, 255))

cmp_img = Image.composite(image, new_img, image).quantize(colors=256, method=2)

cmp_img.save("Destination_path.bmp")
```

**OUTPUT IMAGE:-**

[image]

Comment: oh it's getting closer now! now my program can read the output file and detect a background to hide. but it still looks really unnatural without a background.

Comment: if my program removes background(#FF00FF) color, it looks like a gloomy pink color sticking around blue color. can i at least colour them nearby colors? to looks more natural..

Comment: @Bora So what is the problem? Did the method i stated in the answer did not work for you? As it outputs an image where any non opaque pixel of the original image, has the value of magenta(#FF00FF).

Comment: Yeah but not completely.. theres still non-exactly-magenta color around the image. Removing them was the whole point of every question i have been asking

Comment: @Bora the reason for that is,  because your input image contains a range of alpha value. I. E. Their exists  regions of your image aren't total opaque or transparent,  meaning they have 0 < alpha < 255. Secondly,  we can't get rid of these semi transparent regions as the original image uses it for smooth border effects. Therefore,  flattening each semi transparent pixel value to a fully opaque one won't work,  as it might ruin the image

Comment: Oh oh now i understand ... so thats the best pillow can do.. thank you so much hehe XD